# How to get (fast) first non-Nan daily value of a DataFrame while keeping the shape and index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `pd.DataFrame`

```
from datetime import datetime
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]],
    index=[
        datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 10), datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 15), datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 20), datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 25),
        datetime(2020, 1, 2, 1, 10), datetime(2020, 1, 2, 1, 15), datetime(2020, 1, 2, 1, 20), datetime(2020, 1, 2, 1, 25)
    ]
)
```

I would like to convert it into the following form:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
    index=[
        datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 10), datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 15), datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 20), datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 25),
        datetime(2020, 1, 2, 1, 10), datetime(2020, 1, 2, 1, 15), datetime(2020, 1, 2, 1, 20), datetime(2020, 1, 2, 1, 25)
    ]
)
```

I have managed to achieve this in the following way:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1[col].loc[df1[col].replace(0, np.nan).groupby(df1.index.date).idxmax()].dropna().reindex(df1.index) for col in df1.columns], axis=1).replace(np.nan, 0).astype(int)
```

such that `df2.equals(df3)` evalautes to True.

My problem is that my way is quite slow for a large `pd.DataFrame` and I am wondering how it can be made much faster?

Comment: What is the rule to convert a duplicated row to `[0,0,0]`?

Comment: The grouping is by column, not by row (or maybe I am misunderstanding your question) ?

Comment: nevermind I read the question clearer, I understand it now, ill have a go later on

Comment: @Newskooler What would be the output of this `df1 = pd.DataFrame(     data=[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]],     index=[         datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 10), datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 15), datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 20), datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 25),         datetime(2020, 1, 2, 1, 10), datetime(2020, 1, 2, 1, 15), datetime(2020, 1, 2, 1, 20), datetime(2020, 1, 2, 1, 25)     ] )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution:

just get the first 1 value in each row:

```
df1[df1.cumsum(axis=1)!=1] = 0
```

set a temporary date col

```
df1["date"] = df1.index.date
```

set any duplicated rows to 0

```
df1[df1.duplicated()] = 0
```

get rid of the temporary date column

```
df1.drop("date", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This roughly halved the run time on my pc:

For 100 loops:

The questions method: 7.292934599994624s

Method 1: 0.3330558000016026s

There could be some optimization by not making a temporary date column, but I'm not sure how to do this. Hopefully, someone with more pandas knowledge could let me know!

This code also assumes that the data is already sorted by date

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import timeit

n = 200

data = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]*n
index = [[datetime(y, 1, 1, 1, x) for x in [10, 15, 20, 25]] for y in range(2020, 2020+n)]
index = [item for sublist in index for item in sublist]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=data,
    index=index
)

def method1(df):
    return pd.concat([df[col].loc[df[col].replace(0, np.nan).groupby(df.index.date).idxmax()].dropna().reindex(df.index) for col in df.columns], axis=1).replace(np.nan, 0).astype(int)

def method2(df):
    df3 = df.copy()
    df3[df3.cumsum(axis=1)!=1] = 0
    df3["date"] = df3.index.date
    df3[df3.duplicated()] = 0
    df3.drop("date", axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df3

start = timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(100):
    new_df = method1(df1)
end = timeit.default_timer()
print(end-start)

start = timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(100):
    new_df = method2(df1)
end = timeit.default_timer()
print(end-start)
```

Comment: I found method2 to be quickest of all submissions until now. Thanks.

Comment: @Newskooler No worries, Ive got a few more ideas im going to try out later :)

Comment: @Newskooler I've added another method that is ever so slightly faster. I also found that when the data frame is much larger, you get a much better performance boost, I'm getting 24x faster on my PC with a larger data frame

Comment: method3 did not produce the same results as method2 or method1 when I tested it.

Comment: @Newskooler Okay, I'll delete it as the performance was basically the same anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean masking or [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html). Then use [`pd.Series.first_valid_idnex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html) in `groupby`.

```
def func(g): 
    vals = np.zeros(g.shape) 
    idx = g.index.get_indexer(g.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index).tolist()) 
    vals[idx, np.arange(len(g.columns))] = 1 
    return pd.DataFrame(vals, index=g.index, columns=g.columns)

m = df1.eq(1)
df1[m].groupby(df1.index.date).apply(func).astype(int)


                     0  1  2
2020-01-01 01:10:00  0  0  1
2020-01-01 01:15:00  0  1  0
2020-01-01 01:20:00  1  0  0
2020-01-01 01:25:00  0  0  0
2020-01-02 01:10:00  0  0  1
2020-01-02 01:15:00  0  1  0
2020-01-02 01:20:00  1  0  0
2020-01-02 01:25:00  0  0  0
```

Comment: @MustafaAydın Yes it should. I got this as output`rec.array([('2020-01-01T01:10:00.000000000', 0, 0, 1),
           ('2020-01-01T01:15:00.000000000', 0, 1, 0),
           ('2020-01-01T01:20:00.000000000', 1, 0, 1),
           ('2020-01-01T01:25:00.000000000', 0, 0, 0),
           ('2020-01-02T01:10:00.000000000', 0, 0, 1),
           ('2020-01-02T01:15:00.000000000', 0, 1, 0),
           ('2020-01-02T01:20:00.000000000', 1, 0, 0),
           ('2020-01-02T01:25:00.000000000', 0, 0, 0)],
          dtype=[('index', '<M8[ns]'), ('0', '<i8'), ('1', '<i8'), ('2', '<i8')])`

Comment: @MustafaAydın `df1[df1.shift().ne(df1)].fillna(0).astype(int).to_records()`'s output is the above comment.

Comment: @MustafaAydın Edited my answer. I misunderstood the question previously.

Comment: Works well and as expected. I found method2 in @Tom McLean's answer to be about 33% or so quicker.  You have a small bug `vals[idx, np.arange(len(df.columns))] = 1 ` should be `vals[idx, np.arange(len(g.columns))] = 1 `

Comment: @Newskooler Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed it. Yes, Tom's is better than mine. I'll other alternatives to see if could come up with a better answer.